# Accessing request parameters django

Tags: django

Hi I am trying to capture sms parameters from a request that comes in this format

```
b'name=kcom-sms04&number=%2B255688121131&content=Hello'
```

Above appears when I print HttpRequest.body

How can I access number, content and name parameters? I use django.

Comment: THis is likely a POST request, so you can access these with `request.POST`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**: use `request.POST`.

Normally these are POST parameters, you can access these with [**`request.POST`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST), which is a [**`QueryDict`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict). A `QueryDict` is a dictionary-like object, but where a key can map to multiple values.

For example, you can access `'kcom-sms04'` with `request.POST['name']`.